# Writing an AWT widget

Tags: java, widget, awt

I fear I'm just making a ten-times duplicate question, but I've been trying to Google this for quite some time without finding anything, neither in general nor even here on SO, so I'm starting to think it's worth a shot.

I'm wondering, is there a good guide on what is necessary to implement an AWT widget in Java? What needs to be implemented in order to respond to such things as redrawing, resizing, placement, focus behavior and all other such things as widgets may or should do, in a proper manner? All the articles I manage to find describe the process from the perspective of a user of widgets, never from the perspective of the one implementing them.

Also, what would be the primary differences between implementing an AWT widget and implementing a Swing widget? Is there even a difference from the implementer's point of view?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to learn how to write an AWT widget would be to look at the source code for an AWT widget.  Here's the source code for the [java.awt.Frame](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Frame.java) class.

I haven't worked with AWT much, but Swing is much better from the GUI developer's point of view.  The only difference that I know about from the implementer's point of view is Swing's usage of Listeners.

Again, you can look at the source code to see what's different.  Here's the source code for the [javax.swing.JFrame](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/javax/swing/JFrame-source.html) class

Comment: Well, that doesn't really work very well, since the AWT widgets don't actually do any of the real widget work, but just delegates it to the native peers. And as for Swing, it's so complex with pluggable looks and feels and stuff that I think pure guesswork would be faster than digging through it. :)

Comment: @Dolda2000: I've always extended Swing components to get what I want.  I've never tried to write a Swing component from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Not too much difference aside from the fact that AWT widgets are simpler.

You extend one of the 4 classes: Component, Container, Canvas, Panel. The first two are heavyweight, the latter two are lightweight (don't have native window system peers). Override paint(Graphics) (or update()) and getPreferredSize() to make it visible, then look into javadocs for overriding event handling methods.

Sure you know this link, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html